# how to show page numbers on the html footer when print out?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to show page numbers at the footer on chrome browser using JavaScript and CSS. Apparently browsers no longer support following CSS code:

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    counter-increment: pages; 
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

I tried to use following JavaScript libraries they do work but I already use ngx-print in my Angular project. These libraries changed the DOM dramatically and my Angular project did not load.

https://www.pagedmedia.org/pagedjs-sneak-peeks/

https://github.com/byuarchdi/print-headers-and-footers

There is a jQuery solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LeonVFX/zscoopoc/) but I cannot use jQuery.

I would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on how to show print page number using JavaScript and CSS.

The worst scenario would be to convert above jQuerycode to plain JavaScript code.

Comment: hey, @johnny did you achieve this yet?